# How to make batch insert in mongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using java for insert data into mongo db .
I have some values in my array list. i want to insert it as batch in mongo db.

IS there any functions available with mongo db for batch data insertion?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

By using `DBCollection.insert` u can do.It accepts a parameter of type `DBObject`, `List<DBObject>`.
If you are passing in a string array.

You can manually create documents(DBObjects), insert them to a List or an array of DBObjects.

```
DBObject doc_1 = new BasicDBObject();
doc_1.put("name", "XXX");
doc_1.put("age", 20);
DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject():
doc.add("name", "YYY");    
List<DBObject> doc_List = new ArrayList<>();
doc_List .add(doc);
doc_List .add(doc_1);
collection.insert(doc_List );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
please say how we can update a mongodb table as batch process

Comment: If i am not miss understand u looking for bulk update in Mangodb. Please have a look on this link "http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/". if this is not your requirement let me know so i can go other solution.

Comment: I gone through the above url but they are showing file not found.
please give any other helpful links.
thanks in advance